# Pressed button effect for Bootstrap 3 button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I have create the bootply demo in here http://bootply.com/110656

I want to create pressed button effect like tutorial on http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/13/creative-button-styles/. But somehow, the pressed effect is not working. only the drop shadow is moving, not the button.

I've played with `top` and `box-shadow` for many times, but still not working, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep in mind that, `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` css properties works with the `absolute` or `relative` or `fixed` positioned elements. Clicked or pressed event is called as `:active` pseudo css class. In your case, you have to use the following styles.

```
.btn-custom {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #285e8e;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-custom:hover {
    top: 2.5px;
    border-bottom-width: 2.5px;
}

.btn-custom:active {
    top: 5px;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Please check this bootply example: http://bootply.com/110673 .

Comment: Thank you, I missed the `position: relative`. It's working now

Comment: Ah, but the element after the button is affected when clicked or hovered, I've updated your bootply

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I use box-shadow properties instead of border-bottom